# Cancel button does not execute action

Tags: swift, menu, ios8, xcode6.1

I created a project with six View over to the View menu that has a cancel button. if you are in one of the View from 2 to 6 and I open the menu, and then I press cancels hypothetically I return to View 1, how can I change the code so as to leave the current view? Also insert the code ....

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainViewController (sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Thanks for aid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UINavigationController` has a `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` method to roll back to the root view controller.

If your view 1 is also the root view controller, and you are using a navigation controller, then you can use the following line of code:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: I tried already but when I press cancels always returns to View 1 and remains on view selected (if I am in View 2 and I access the menu and hit cancels must remain in View 2, and so on) anyway thanks for the help ...

Comment: I'm wondering if your question is ambiguous... do you want to return to the root view controller when cancel is tapped or what?

Comment: I do not know maybe I explained I hurt another example: if I am in View 1 (MainViewController) and I access the menu when I press cancels return to View 1 and so everything is right. If I find myself in the View 2 (ProfileViewController) and I access the menu and hit cancels should remain in View 2 instead switches to View 1 and I do not want this. how can I do?

Comment: Please post the code of the `Cancel` tap handler in your question.

Comment: This is the code of the project starting [link](https://github.com/mathewsanders/Custom-Menu-Transition-Swift-Tutorial)

Comment: I solved this way thanks anyway aid. This is the code used: 'code' @IBAction func CloseBtn(sender: AnyObject) {         self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)     }